# Importing excel file into mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert excel file into database my code is :

```
<?php

require_once 'Excel/reader.php';
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
$data->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
$data->read('Excel/exceltestsheet.xls');

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("dbname",$conn);

for ($x == 2; $x <== count($data->sheets[0]["cells"]); $x++) 
{
$name = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][1];
$extension = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][2];
$email = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][3];
$sql = "INSERT INTO msg (name,extension,email) 
    VALUES ('$name',$extension,'$email')";
echo $sql."\n";
mysql_query($sql);
} 
?>
```

When I insert then I am getting an error which is 
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\wamp\www\uploadexcel.php on line 11`

Comment: change this part: `for ($x == 2; $x <==` to `for ($x = 2; $x <=` in for loop we need only one equal sign, using double sign is an operator for checking if the value assigned to that or not

Comment: i got an error when i change the line: for ($x = 2; $x <= count($data->sheets[0]["cells"]); $x++) and the error is Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\Excel\reader.php on line 261 The filename Excel/exceltestsheet.xls is not readable

Answer (score 1):

Change -

```
for ($x == 2; $x <== count($data->sheets[0]["cells"]); $x++)
```

To

```
for ($x = 2; $x <= count($data->sheets[0]["cells"]); $x++)
```

As a suggestion, I believe you should save your Excel into a folder and save handles in the database instead of saving the whole sheet(if this is what you written in the title)

Comment: i got an error when i change the line: for ($x = 2; $x <= count($data->sheets[0]["cells"]); $x++) and the error is  Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\Excel\reader.php on line 261            The filename Excel/exceltestsheet.xls is not readable

Comment: @afrozahmad it is something else from what you asked in the question , however you can try `$data =& new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();`

Answer (score 0):

Replace line 261 on reader.php with:

```
$this->_ole = new OLERead();
```

i.e

```
$this->_ole =& new OLERead();
```

now replaced with:

```
$this->_ole = new OLERead();
```

this stopped the Deprecated error issue for me.